# Getting a phone number in Sweden without having a personnummer

Tags: sweden, telephone

Is there a way to get a swedish mobile phone number while in Sweden without having a personnummer? I will be moving there soon and I was going to send some of my stuff with Eurosender, but apparently they also need a local phone number to do the delivery. The only telephone companies I have found are Telenor Sverige and Telia. Are there any other major carriers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major carriers are:

- Telia
- Telenor
- Tre (3)
- Tele2/Comviq

While in Sweden you can get a prepaid SIM from any of them (except Tele2 but including Comviq) at for example [Pressbyrån](https://www.pressbyran.se/handla-hos-oss/merpapressbyran/) or [7-Eleven](https://www.7-eleven.se/i-butiken/produkter-tjanster/)
but I'm afraid none of the carriers ship SIMs abroad. Registering a personnummer can be done later with the carrier for some extra benefits but is optional.

Topping up online probably require a Nordic or even Swedish debit/credit card, but you can buy top up vouchers in shops.

Comment: You can top prepaids in 7 eleven or Pressbyrån at the cashiers

Answer (score 1):

You could buy and use a SIM card meant for a tourist.

[This article](https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-sweden/) at [toomanyadapters.com](http://toomanyadapters.com) reports that the author — presumably not a Swedish citizen, and thus without a Swedish personnumer - was able to buy a SIM card at a cellphone shop without presenting ID. The article also mentions obtaining a SIM card overseas (i.e., before traveling to Sweden), so you have the card when you enter Sweden.

I don't know if there are restrictions on how long such a card might be used, although the article notes that the card can be topped up online.

Answer (score 1):

[I was able to get a SIM card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121020/european-sim-card-in-us-mobile-phone) from Telia without a personnummer, but I cannot call/text numbers outside of Sweden using it. I can receive international calls, I just can't make them. I don't know if this is a Telia restriction, or if this is a national policy that all the carriers must follow.

I can top it up online with no problems, since it's registered with my email address.